# Issue with 'style.theme_create' python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I ran into this error in `theme_create`: `self.tk.call(self._name, "theme", "create", themename, _tkinter.TclError: Theme name already exists`

and I want to know if there is a way to check if my theme is already initialized when I refresh the window

Here is the part of the code where the error exists :

```py
style = ttk.Style()
BG_COLOUR="#2d5b6b"

style.theme_create(
    "name", parent="alt", settings = {
        ".": {"configure": {"background": BG_COLOUR,
                            "foreground": "black",
                            "font": ("HIND", 12),
                            "relief": "flat"}},
        "TLabel": {"configure": {"foreground": "white",
                "padding": 10
                }},
        "TNotebook": {"configure": {"tabmargins": [2, 5, 2, 0]}
                    },
        "TNotebook.Tab": {
            "configure": {"relief" : "flat",
                        "foreground": "white",
                        "bordercolor" : BG_COLOUR,
                        "darkcolor" : BG_COLOUR,
                        "borderwifth":0,
                        "lightcolor" : BG_COLOUR,
                        "padding": [5, 1], "background": BG_COLOUR
                        },
            "map": {"background": [("selected", "#456975")],
                    "foreground": [("selected", "#ff6815")],

                    "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])]}},
        "Treeview":{
            "configure":{

                "foreground":"#000000",
                "rowheight":20,
                "relief":"flat",
                "fieldbackground":"#E1E1E1"},
            "map": {"background": [("selected", BG_COLOUR)],
                    "foreground": [("selected", "white")],
            }
        },
        "Treeview.Heading":{
            "configure":{
                "background":BG_COLOUR,
                "foreground":"white"
                }
        }

    })
style.theme_use("name")
```

Comment: It means that you are trying to create a style with ```name``` name but another style with ```name``` name already exists

Comment: I used try and except to check if the style already exists and it worked thanks for your reply